# Why the type of a mock does not match Mock?

Tags: python-3.x, types, mocking, identity

My code:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from unittest.mock import Mock

a = datetime.now()
print(id(type(a)))
print(id(datetime))

b = Mock()
print(id(Mock))
print(id(type(b)))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 foo.py
4477748792
4477748792
140351771879768
140351771828664
```

Why is it that `type(a)` and `datetime` the same? But `type(b)` and `Mock` are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the Mock class it has

```py
class Mock(CallableMixin, NonCallableMock):
```

Now if you explore `NonCallableMock`

```py
class NonCallableMock(Base):
    """A non-callable version of `Mock`"""

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        # every instance has its own class
        # so we can create magic methods on the
        # class without stomping on other mocks
        new = type(cls.__name__, (cls,), {'__doc__': cls.__doc__})
        instance = object.__new__(new)
        return instance
```

It clearly mentions that a new instance is created using a new class at run-time so one Mock doesn't interfere with other. That is why you are seeing `id` different because the actual class for the object is generated at runtime